# What does "chown nginx:nginx * -R" do?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, wildcard, chown

I understand what the command `chown nginx:nginx -R` does.

**My question is regarding the star `*` wildcard.**

So essentially what I'm asking is what is what is the difference between these three commands:

1. `chown nginx:nginx * -R`
2. `chown nginx:nginx . -R`
3. `chown nginx:nginx .* -R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one changes group/owner permissions on everything within the current working directory, but not the current working directory itself:

```
chown nginx:nginx * -R
```

The next one changes permissions on the current directory, and everything in it:

```
chown nginx:nginx . -R
```

The final one does the same thing as the second:

```
chown nginx:nginx .* -R
```

Comment: The final one doesn't do the same thing as the second. It only affects hidden files (filenames starting with a '.').

Comment: You are right, I was testing without '-R' by mistake. However, in my test it also chown's everything in the parent directory due to '..' being picked up the '.*'.

Answer (score 0):

It means all files in current directory. Symbol `*` shouldn't be used with flag `-R`. For example:

Change the owner for all files in current directory:

```
chown nginx:nginx ./*
```

Or change the owner for all files in directory /var/www/html/

```
chown nginx:nginx /var/www/html/*
```

**NOTE:** Don't changing owner for hidden files (like `.htaccess`). For changing hidden files use: `chown nginx:nginx ./.*`